# Latent Change Score Modelling

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, mathematical-modeling, programming, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I am currently undertaking a research project that aims to assess the effectiveness of an intervention program. However, I am encountering difficulties in locating suitable resources for my study.
Specifically, I am in search of papers and tutorials on multivariate multigroup latent change modelling. My research involves evaluating the impact of the intervention program in the absence of a control group, while also investigating the influence of pre-test scores on subsequent changes. Additionally, I am keen to explore how the scores differ across various demographic groups, such as age, gender, and knowledge level (all measured as categorical variables).
Although I have come across several resources on univariate/bivariate latent change modelling with more than three time points, I have been unable to find papers that specifically address my requirements—namely, studies focusing on two time points, multiple latent variables (n >= 3), and multiple indicators for each latent variable (n >= 2).
I would greatly appreciate your assistance and guidance in recommending any relevant papers, tutorials, or alternative resources that pertain to my research objectives.

Best,
V. P.